# Calculating volume weighted prices in Array columns for a specific volume in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, clickhouse

I have the following table, all arrays have the same size (Example: 25)

```
bid_prices: array
bid_quantity: array
ask_prices: array
ask_quantity: array
```

I am interested in a certain quantity, for example: 8

I need to compute the volume weighted price for both bid and ask for this size (so that would be the price of a taker order, for the financial interpretation): for example for the bid side

```
bid_prices = [101,100,99,98,97]
bid_quantity = [1,2,3,10,5]
size = 8
adjusted_bid_quantity = [1,2,3,2]  (the sum of the quantity exactly = 8)
resized_prices = [101,100,99,98] (we only need the first 4 prices)
```

then we can compute the vwap bid = (101 * 1+100 * 2+99 * 3+98 * 2)/8

The code below (using clickhouse) is working but

- I would like to optimize it
- The idea is to run it for different size, any way to do this in one shot ?

```
WITH
     resizing AS (
        SELECT
        exchange_ts,
        arrayFilter(x -> x < 8,arrayCumSum( bids_qty ) ) as temp_bids_qty_cumsum,
        arrayResize(bids_qty,length( temp_bids_qty_cumsum )) as temp_resized_bid_qty,
        arrayPushBack(temp_resized_bid_qty,8 - temp_bids_qty_cumsum[LENGTH(temp_bids_qty_cumsum)]) as resized_bid_qty,
        arrayResize(bids,length(resized_bid_qty)) as resized_bid_prices,
                        
        arrayFilter(x -> x < 8,arrayCumSum( asks_qty ) ) as temp_asks_qty_cumsum,
        arrayResize(asks_qty,length( temp_asks_qty_cumsum )) as temp_resized_ask_qty,
        arrayPushBack(temp_resized_ask_qty,8 - temp_asks_qty_cumsum[LENGTH(temp_asks_qty_cumsum)]) as resized_ask_qty,
        arrayResize(asks,length(resized_ask_qty)) as resized_ask_prices
                        
        FROM my_db.books AS t
        WHERE toDateTime64(exchange_ts/1000, 3) >= '2023-10-27 00:00:00' 
            AND toDateTime64(exchange_ts/1000, 3) <= '2023-10-28 00:00:00'
         )
        SELECT
           toDateTime64(r.exchange_ts/1000, 3) as ts,
           if(length(r.resized_bid_prices) <=  25, arraySum(arrayMap((x, y) -> x * y, r.resized_bid_prices, r.resized_bid_qty)) / arraySum(r.resized_bid_qty), NAN) as bid_vwap,
           if(length(r.resized_ask_prices) <=  25, arraySum(arrayMap((x, y) -> x * y, r.resized_ask_prices, r.resized_ask_qty)) / arraySum(r.resized_ask_qty), NAN) as ask_vwap
        FROM resizing AS r
        ORDER by ts ASC
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a lot going on, so I don't fully understand what you're trying to compute. Check out the following:

```
WITH
    [101, 100, 99, 98, 97] AS bid_prices,
    [1, 2, 3, 10, 5] AS bid_quantity
SELECT sumArray(arrayMap((a, b) -> (a * b), bid_prices, bid_quantity)) / sumArray(bid_quantity)
```

It computes the following, which seems pretty much what you want:

```
(101*1 + 100*2 + 99*3 + 98*10 + 97*5) / (1 + 2 + 3 + 10 + 5)
```

Comment: Thanks Rich for your answer!
In your example, what is missing is my constraint in terms of cumulative quantity.
Let's say I am interested in a cumulative_quantity = 8.

I should work with
[1,2,3,2] for the quantities  (I drop the index 5 and the index 4 is replaced by 2 to have a cumulative size of 8). Then, the prices I can use for the computation are 
[101,100, 99, 98] as I don't need index 5

Comment: I see some Python in your future :)  But seriously, you might be able to do this with SQL...curious to see if someone figures it out. It's a bit out of my range!

Comment: Right, I first did it in python but I thought I could speed up the computation usin the power of clickhouse. I managed to write a query that works but it is not super fancy, I am sure I can do better. I edited my first post with my solution (remark: max length of array is 25, so having 26 means there is no such size in the array and we should return NaN). Thanks again for taking a look !